# Appending a text file to a text file

Tags: python, file, text

I've run to a error. I've been trying to append a text file to itself like so:

```
file_obj = open("text.txt", "a+")
number = 6

def appender(obj, num):
    count = 0
    while count<=num:
        read = file_obj.read()
        file_obj.seek(0,2)
        file_obj.write(read)
        count+=1

appender(file_obj, number)
```

However, the `text.txt` file is then filled with strange ASCII symbols. At first, the file contains only a simple "hello", but after the code, it contains this:

```
hellohello䀀 猀· d娀 Ť搀Ŭ娀ͤ攀ɪ昀Ѥ萀 夀ɚ搀ť樀Ŧ搀茀 婙ݤ攀Ѫ昀ࡤ萀 夀њ搀   
ɥ攀ժ昀൤
茀 婙୤攀ť樀ɦ搀茀 婙൤萀 ݚ搀࡚攀४攀ƃ娀਍搀⡓ 癳  祐桴湯䌠慨慲瑣牥䴠灡楰杮
䌠摯捥挠ㅰ㔲‰敧敮慲整⁤牦浯✠䅍偐义升嘯久佄卒䴯䍉䙓⽔䥗䑎坏⽓偃㈱〵吮员‧楷桴朠湥潣敤⹣祰
മഊ椊 and so on.
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Most of that is not ASCII, as shown here in the question...

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem shown; all I get is the two "hello" characters.  What Python version are you using?  What OS?

Comment: When you get to a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful things and accept your favourite answer (even if you have to write it yourself), so Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I can fix your problem, even though I can't reproduce it.  There's a logic error: after you write, you fail to return to the start of the file for reading.  In terms of analysis, you failed to do anything to diagnose the problem.  At the very least, use a `print` statement to see what you're reading: that highlights the problem quite well.  Here's the loop I used:

```
count = 0
while count<=num:
    file_obj.seek(0)      # Read from the beginning of the file.
    read = file_obj.read()
    print(count, read)    # Trace what we're reading.
    file_obj.seek(0, 2)
    file_obj.write(read)
    count+=1
```

This gives the expected output of 128 (2^(6+1)) repetitions of "hello".

**EXTENSIONS**

I recommend that you learn to use both the `for` loop and the `with open ... as` idiom.  These will greatly shorten your program and improve the readability.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this code and everything is working as expected:

```
with open("file.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        f.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have the wrong mode - use `'r+'` rather than `'a+'`. See [this link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_files_io.htm) for a list of modes and an explanation of reading files.